# Facebook Ads API: How can I get CPA reach estimate (bids) just like CPA or CPM does

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Recently, facebook releases their ads API for CPA-based ads.

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/cost-per-action-ads/)

I'm working on adding this features to my project.
Does anyone know how to get the bid range estimations for CPA-based targeting?
Just like what we do to get CPC or CPM ones.

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/reachestimate/)

The response from reachestimate only contains CPC and CPM bid ranges.

Comment: Do you know if is there any API to get reach estimate of Facebook's users? Just like the Audience Insight does.